# Advanced Custom fields unable to get fields with ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working on a project that adds a "load more" posts button using ajax to my website.

Without ACF my call works perfectly and I can get all my blog post data fine, however I use ACF to style my posts and because I use a few if statements my styling is "hidden" caused by ajax not passing the data to the ACF fields (I think...?)

How do I get ajax to load my acf data properly.

Any help would be amazing!

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
              // JS to submit ajax for load more button
              $(document).on('click', '#load-more-posts', function(e) {
                $('#load-more-posts-error').hide();
                var previouspaged = $(this).attr('data-paged');
                var currentpaged = parseInt(previouspaged) + 1;
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: wp_ajax_url,
                    data: {
                      action: 'load_more_posts',
                      paged: currentpaged,
                      context: $(this).attr('data-context'),
                      query: load_more_data.query,
                      nonce: $('#load-more-posts-nonce').val(),
                    },
                    dataType: 'html'
                  })
                  .done(function(response) {
                    if (response) {
                      $('#load-more-posts-area-wrapper').append(response);
                      if (currentpaged > parseInt($('#load-more-posts').attr('data-max-pages'))) {
                        $('#load-more-posts').hide();
                      } else {
                        $('#load-more-posts').attr('data-paged', currentpaged);
                      }
                    } else {
                      $('#load-more-posts').hide();
                      $('#load-more-posts-error').show();
                    }
                  });
                e.preventDefault();
              });
            });
```

Added load more function: -

```
                /**
                 * Ajax handler for load more posts
                 */
                public function load_more_posts() {


                    $location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
                    require ($location . '/emerald/wp-load.php');


                    if ( empty( $_POST['nonce'] ) || empty( $_POST['paged'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'load-more-posts-nonce-'  . $_POST['context'] ) ) {
                       exit;
                    } else {



                        global $post; // required by setup post data


                        $context = ( ! empty( $_POST['context'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['context'] ) : 'default';
                        $args = (array) $_POST['query'];
                        $args['paged'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['paged'] );

                        // A filter if you want to customize the query
                        $args = apply_filters( 'load-more-posts-args-' . sanitize_text_field( $_POST['context'] ), $args );

                        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                        $posts = $query->get_posts();
                        foreach( $posts as $post ) {
                            setup_postdata( $post );
                            get_template_part('page-builder/layouts/ajax/recent-posts', $context);
                            wp_reset_postdata();
                        }
                    }
                    exit;
                }
            }
            new Load_More_Posts();
```

Updated to add recent posts template: -

```
    <?php



    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    echo "<div";
    css_class();
    echo ">";

    // Params



    if ( have_rows( 'card_list_options', $post_id  ) ) :
    while ( have_rows( 'card_list_options', $post_id ) ) : the_row();



    if ( have_rows( 'card_options', $post_id ) ) :
    while ( have_rows( 'card_options', $post_id ) ) : the_row();
    $title_check = get_sub_field( 'show_title', $post_id );
    $date_check = get_sub_field( 'show_date', $post_id );
    $cat_check = get_sub_field( 'show_category', $post_id );
    $exc_check = get_sub_field( 'show_excerpt', $post_id ) ;
    $tags_check = get_sub_field( 'show_tags' );
    $button_check = get_sub_field( 'show_read_more', $post_id );
    $alt_thumb_Check = get_sub_field( 'use_alternative_featured_image', $post_id );
    endwhile;
    endif;


    if ( have_rows( 'card_style', $post_id ) ) :
    while ( have_rows( 'card_style', $post_id ) ) : the_row();
    $title_size = get_sub_field( 'title_size', $post_id );
    $readmore_style = get_sub_field( 'read_more_button_style', $post_id );
    $button_text = get_sub_field( 'read_more_button_text', $post_id );
    endwhile;
    endif;




    $card = get_sub_field('card_style', $post_id);
    $card_options = get_sub_field('card_options', $post_id);




     if ( have_rows( 'source', $post_id ) ) :
    while ( have_rows( 'source', $post_id ) ) : the_row();


    $post_count = get_sub_field('show_x_posts', $post_id);
    $post_type = get_sub_field('select_post_type', $post_id);
    $post_offset = get_sub_field('select_post_offset', $post_id);



    endwhile;
    endif;

    endwhile;
    endif;



    // WP_Query arguments
    $args = array(
    //  'nopaging'               => false,
      'posts_per_page'         => $post_count,
      'post_type'              => array( $post_type ),
      //'page_id'                => $post_id,
        //'paged' => 1,
    //  'paged' => $paged,
     'offset'                 => $post_count,
    );

    // The Query
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(  $args );



    // Adds customisation options + container class for internal div
    echo '<div';
    css_class();
    echo '>';
    echo '<ul id="inf_scroll" class="list-unstyled row card_list">';


    $link = get_permalink();



    // start li
    echo '<li class="news p-b-sm';

    if ( have_rows( 'card_list_options' ) ) :
    while ( have_rows( 'card_list_options' ) ) : the_row();

    if ( have_rows( 'card_layout' ) ) {

        $col_size = array();

      while ( have_rows( 'card_layout') ) : the_row();
        $col_size [] = get_sub_field('lg');
        $col_size [] = get_sub_field('md', $post_id);
        $col_size [] = get_sub_field('sm', $post_id);
        $col_size [] = get_sub_field('xs', $post_id);
      endwhile;


      foreach ($col_size as $col) {
        echo $col . ' ' ;
      }

    }
    endwhile;
    endif;
    echo '">';

    echo '<article class="white-background">';

    //check if element has a thumbnail
    //if not the replace the thumbnail with a category link
    if ( $alt_thumb_Check  == 1 ) {

            $add_alt_feature_image = get_field( 'add_alt_feature_image' );
         if ( $add_alt_feature_image ) {
             echo '<a class="greyscale"  href="' . $link . '">';
             echo '<img class="img-fluid" src="'. $add_alt_feature_image['url'] . '" alt="'. $add_alt_feature_image['alt'] .'"/>';
             echo '</a>';
         }

    } else {
            echo '<a  href="' . $link . '">';
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'post_thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'img-fluid p-b-sm' ));
            echo '</a>';
    }

    echo '<span class="cardbody">';


    $title = get_the_title();

    if ($title_check == 1) {
        echo '<a  href="' . $link . '">' . '<' . $title_size . '>' . $title . '</' . $title_size . '>'  . '</a>';
    }

    // Control to show/display the post date
    if ($date_check == 1) {
        $date = get_the_date();
        echo '<small class="p-b-sm">' . $date . '</small>' ;
    }


    if ( $cat_check  == 1 ) {
                                                     the_category();
                    }



    // Display the post excerpt
    if ($exc_check == 1) {
        the_excerpt($post->ID);
    }


    // Display post tags
    if ($tags_check == 1) {


        if (get_the_tag_list()) {
          echo '<p><small>tags:</small></p>';
            echo get_the_tag_list('<ul class="tag_list"><li>', '</li><li>', '</li></ul>');
        }
    }

    echo "</span>";



    if ($button_check == 1) {
          echo '<a class="m-t-sm readmore '. $readmore_style .'" href="' . $link . '">' . $button_text  . '</a>';
    }




    //end article
    echo "</article>";

    // end li
    echo "</li>";



    echo "</ul>";


    echo '<div id="inf_load_footer"></div>';

    echo "</div>";
```

Comment: your question is unclear, what you expect from ACF?  Are you doing ACF stuff in `load_more_posts` which doesn't work, if that is the case we need codes of `load_more_posts` function

Comment: @cjmling Updated my post, basically from my template (recent-posts) I have a class(bootstrap grid class) that lays out my page.

However when my posts are loaded its missing the class.

Comment: We still don't see any ACF codes here. You are using ACF to style your post, and the post is being styled in template `recent-posts` right? And thats where you use ACF right?  The problem should be in there I assume.

Comment: @cjmling Updated the post to show the recent-posts code.